# Configuring Helios WTP utility project's build path with EAR Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ear, eclipse-wtp

I create three projects:  An EAR parent project, an EJB child project, and a Utility child Project.  I add a jar and the utility project to the "Ear Module Assembly".  In both child projects I put the jar in the MANIFEST.MF classpath, and both projects have EAR Libraries on their build path.  From eclipse all of the classes in the jar can be found from the EJB project, but not from the Utility project.  In order to get the jar on the utility projects build path I have to add it seperate from the Ear Libraries.

If you look at the properties of EAR Libraries from the "configure build path" window, it says "The EAR Libraries classpath container dynamically computes the Java EE project's module classpath dependencies using the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF Class-Path entries."

Why does this only work for the EJB projects build-path but not the utility project?  If utility projects cannot use EAR libraries for the build-path but only for the runtime class-path then why was it even included on the build-path by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utility project's build-path seems to be behaving as expected when switching to Indigo.  Once you add the jar to MANIFEST.MF it shows up on the build-path under EAR Libraries.